# how to add dynamic footer credit in Greatmag theme

Tags: themes, child-theme, copyright

I want to add a dynamic footer copyright credit in my Great mag theme that will automatically updates years like © 2000 - 2018 like this .
Please tell me how to do in in Greatmag theme by a themes.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! For theme-specific questions please contact the theme author directly. Alternatively, if you are not already using a child theme, you may want to set one up and copy whichever file (often `footer.php`) contains the code that you want changed, then modify it within the child theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out knowing the theme personally it's not easy to tell you exactly what you need to do. However, as @WebElaine has pointed out, the code you will need to change will most likely be in your themes `footer.php` file.

It's not recommended to edit themes directly and you should, instead, consider using a WordPress child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

If you have a child theme setup and activated, you should then copy the `footer.php` file from your 'parent' theme to your child themes folder and edit the file where you want your copyright notice displayed.

In order to display the copyright notice as you requested you would need to use something like the following code:

`&copy; 2000 - <?php echo date('Y'); ?>`